# Facebook access token expires even with offline_access

Tags: facebook, oauth

Users login Facebook on my website via an URL that redirects them to
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=116908145XXXXXX&display=page&scope=offline_access&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/account/services/?service=facebookcallback`

On the callback page I make a request with the code I receive to get the access token, at this URL

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=2.3m2hLauQJpWTGFExUK6O3w__.3600.1290081600-100001796185871%7.....&format=json&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Faccount%2Fservices%2F%3Fservice%3Dfacebookcallback&client_id=116908145040447&scope=offline_access&client_secret=...`

The response I get is this
`access_token=116908145XXXXXX|2.3m2hLauQJpWTGFExUK6O3w__.3600.1290081600-100001796185871|S3MG...&expires=3912`

As it can be seen from the token it has an expiration date.

The token expires some hours after the request. Shouldn't I receive an access token without expiration date if I make the requests with scope=offline_access ?

Comment: Well, do you get token expired or you just suppose it will expire?

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but the info might be useful for someone else.

Facebook now disables offline_access by default. You must enable an app migration if you still want to use it.

With the migration off, tokens will be "short lived" and last only an hour or two. You can get an extended token which lasts about 60 days by making a request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

See [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token) for more details

Answer (score 1):

tokens you get with offline_access permissions, are "long-lived" as facebook says in their documentation, but it is not said that it has no expiration / infinite. Even if you get this not-time-bounded access_token, it can still expire if the user changes his password or if he removes your application.

But to answer your question directly, yes you should get a long-lived access_token using "scope=offline_access". Also, please check if the dialog showed "Access my data anytime"

Comment: Yeah, it shows the proper dialog but the token expires in less than a day.

Comment: Quoted from facebook http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
 
    Note: If the application has not requested offline_access permission, the access token is time-bounded. Time-bounded access token also get invalidated when the user logs out of Facebook. If the application has obtained offline_access permission from the user, the access token does not have an expiry. However it gets invalidated whenever the user changes his/her password.